# How to handle slow network connection speed in Android/Glass app?

Tags: android, google-glass

If my Glass app has a slow network connection it starts freezing up and reacting horribly (even though network calls are done on Async tasks in background.)  What do you have to do to make your app responsive even if there are asynch tasks in the background struggling with a slow network connection?

How do you simulate slow network connections on a Glass handset in a dev environment to test error handling cases?

Comment: Are you using a lot of `AsyncTasks` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with slow network connections you can try and have as much data as possible stored locally to the app meaning the app won't have to download as much.

In order to simulate slow network connections you can use one of these tools https://www.raymond.cc/blog/restrict-or-limit-internet-download-and-upload-transfer-speed/
This will only work however if the stuff the stuff the app is downloading is stored across the network, it can't be stored in your computers file system.  A working example would be a raspberry-pi fileselver on your local network.